# how to insert a column value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

A db table consists of 3 columns. But I want to insert a value to one column and I want the other 2 to remain empty. Like database has three input column- roll, date, time, I want only to insert roll. My query:

```
insert into tableName(roll) values ('$_POST['roll'])
```

But I am getting the error message ( Field `attn_time` doesn't have a default value41 ). What would be the correct query?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYts5.jpg)

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs985.jpg)

Comment: `insert into tableName(roll, date, time) values ('$_POST['roll'], NULL, NULL)`

Comment: What does your table structure look like? And you need to read up on sql injection.

Comment: If you're getting the error that attn_time doesn't have a default value then that means the column has the not null attribute set and no default supplied in the definition. The table definition does not support the insert you are trying to perform. Change the table definition or supply a (non-null) value for attn_time.

Answer (score 4):

You need to alter your database table by giving a default value to your `attn_time` column.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this in two ways:

1) Go to your phpmyadmin/mysql and change your columns(attn, attn_time) "Null" property to "Yes". This will allow null value to store in column if non value given.
[You can find "Change" in "Structure" tab in phpmyadmin]

2) You can change your query to

```
insert into tbl1 (roll, attn, attn_time) values ('$roll', null, null)
```

OR

```
insert into tbl1 (roll, attn, attn_time) values ('$roll', '', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$roll=$_POST['roll'];
```

add your validation :

```
insert into tableName(roll) values ('$roll');
```